# Pass object to child then access object methods

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So I have a file `routes.jsx` which handles the routing of my application. Following the [docs](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-redirects-auth-668he?from-embed=&file=/example.js:1669-1991) for `react-router-dom`, I wanted to start working on login/logout.

For now, I have implemented a `fakeAuth` object which will authenticate against the backend and set an `isAuthenticated` var. However, I *think* I need to be able to pass this auth around to different components, such as the `Login.jsx` to actually change the state of `isAuthenticated`, and to let's say a `NavBar.jsx` so I can change a login button to a logout button (to clarify, all my components are functional components (trying) using hooks and do not extend `React.Component` in a class manner).

However, how do I pass the `fakeAuth` as a prop and still have access to the methods inside? If I declare `fakeAuth` inside the `Login.jsx` component, `fakeAuth` is defined. If I pass it in as a prop, it is considered not defined.

**routes.js**

```js
export default (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Route path='/'>
      <LandingPage fakeAuth={fakeAuth}/>  // Landing page has the NavBar component as a child.
    </Route>

    <Switch>
      <Route path="/login">
         <Login fakeAuth={fakeAuth}/> // I want the Login component to have access to fakeAuth.whatever
      </Route>
      <PrivateRoute path="/home">
        <UserApp/>
      </PrivateRoute>
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

const fakeAuth = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  authenticate(cb) {
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated = true;
    setTimeout(cb, 100); // fake async
  },
  signout(cb) {
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated = false;
    setTimeout(cb, 100);
  }
};
```

**Login.jsx**

```js
const Login = ({fakeAuth}) => {
  let history = useHistory();
  let location = useLocation();

  let { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/home" } };
  let login = () => {
    fakeAuth.authenticate(() => {   // Need to access authenticate.
      history.replace(from);
    }); 
  };
  return (
    // login modal etc
    <button onClick={login}>Log in</button>
  );
}
```

The above code is the code that returns `fakeAuth is undefined`.

Any advice would be great!

Comment: Try defining `fakeAuth` on the top of the `routes.js`

Comment: I wouldn't probably go this way because it means juggling with fakeAuth and manually passing it everywhere and would create a Context instead: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html Contexts work great with hooks too!

Comment: @Láďa Durchánek This looks exactly like what I need! Is doing it that way considered "best practice"?

Comment: It is one of the options, works great for smaller apps and is certainly the easiest one to start with before getting to other state management solutions like redux. For your scenario, it will be perfect.